# Are my digital games safe if I lose my Nintendo Switch?

Tags: nintendo-switch

If I purchase Nintendo Switch games through the eShop, are they linked to my account or my Switch?

1. If I lose my Switch or it's stolen, can whoever has my Switch play the games forever? Or can I lock them out somehow?
2. If I buy a new Switch, can I log in and re-download all the games or do I need to buy them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this link](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22434/~/how-to-deactivate-a-nintendo-switch-console), you can lock people out from playing your games by removing all consoles from your Nintendo account, which you can only do once per year.

Your games are tied to your Nintendo account, so you can download them on another switch Switch.